# vis.js current timeline: how to draw the line based on day only

Tags: javascript, vis.js

in vis.js if have option showCurrentTime: true, we will get a current vertical timeline. This vertical line is based on current day, current hour, current second.

Is it possible to have the vertical line based on current day only, without hour, minute and second? (ie. current day, 0 hour, 0 minute and 0 second)

```
var options = {
    showCurrentTime: true,
    orientation: {axis: 'both', item: 'top'}, 
    height: 400,
    margin: {
      axis: 100
   }
}
```

Here is the code https://jsfiddle.net/gbdjbdhv/

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported, but if needed you can always override the `redraw` and `start` methods of the `CurrentTime.js` class to change the behavior as desired. You can find the code of `CurrentTime.js` here:

https://github.com/almende/vis/blob/master/lib/timeline/component/CurrentTime.js

The class is exposed from the vis.js library as:

```
vis.timeline.components.CurrentTime
```